# Get unique entries in a log file using grep

Tags: bash, logging, grep

I have the following logfile

```
2016-05-02 11:37:32,211 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:37:33,065 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /pma/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:37:33,990 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,672 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,719 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,843 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:09,195 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /index on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:09,233 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:09,269 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:10,899 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /index on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:10,935 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:10,970 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:13,307 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /comments on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:13,359 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:13,378 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,106 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,193 (glastopf.glastopf) 31.13.102.123 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,205 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,381 (glastopf.glastopf) 173.252.120.102 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,512 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
```

I want to get unique entries, discarding the first three attributes i.e date time and `glastopf glastopf`. I want to get the unique entrie from the IP onwards. I have the following grep command:

```
sudo grep 'GET\|POST' /home/tsec/prototype/logs/glastopf.log | \
     sort -k4,4 | tac | sort -k4,4 | sort -k1,2 | \
     tail -n 20 > /home/tsec/prototype/logs/extractedlogs/glastopfresult.log
```

There must be something wrong in the sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a task for `sort`:

```
sort -uk4 file.log
```

This will get the first line when multiple lines are identical starting from 4th field, if you want the last entry use `tac` to reverse the lines and do the operation:

```
tac file.log | sort -uk4
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
2016-05-02 11:37:32,211 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:37:33,065 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /pma/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:37:33,990 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,672 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,719 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,843 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:09,195 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /index on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:09,233 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:09,269 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:10,899 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /index on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:10,935 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:10,970 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:13,307 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /comments on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:13,359 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:13,378 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,106 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,193 (glastopf.glastopf) 31.13.102.123 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,205 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,381 (glastopf.glastopf) 173.252.120.102 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,512 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80

$ sort -uk4 file.txt
2016-05-02 11:55:28,512 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,106 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,205 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.27.157 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,843 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,672 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:07,719 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:13,307 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /comments on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:09,195 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /index on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,381 (glastopf.glastopf) 173.252.120.102 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:37:33,990 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:37:32,211 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:37:33,065 (glastopf.glastopf) 190.244.96.69 requested GET /pma/scripts/setup.php on 04680bb24791:80
2016-05-02 11:55:28,193 (glastopf.glastopf) 31.13.102.123 requested GET / on 04680bb24791:80
```